# Nested select with left join in yii ActiveRecord

Tags: php, mysql, yii

I have some tables. Main table is `contractors` and has a linked table `address`, in which there is a certain type of address `(1, 2, 3)`. Required when doing `LEFT JOIN ORDER BY type`, because in some conditions one may be used as well as 1, well as 2 or 3 type of addresses, , but sometimes addresses are not consecutive in the field `type`. 
I made a request which satisfies my requirements, but can not create the same query in ActiveRecord.

So my request directly in the database looks like this:

```
SELECT t.id, addresses.address FROM contractor as t
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM address ORDER BY address.type) as addresses 
    ON addresses.address != '' AND addresses.contractor_id = t.id
    WHERE ((t.type='store') AND (t.name LIKE '%name%' OR addresses.address LIKE '%name%'))
    GROUP BY t.id
```

In model relations this now looks:

```
public function relations(){
  'addresses' => array(
      self::HAS_MANY,
      'Address',
      'contractor_id',
      'on' => "addresses.address != ''",
      'order' => 'addresses.type ASC'
   ),
}
```

I would like to clarify:  I can only use *ActiveRecord*.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use this simple method

```
$criteria = new CDbCriteria;
$criteria->join = 'LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM address ORDER BY address.type) as addresses
ON addresses.address != "" AND addresses.contractor_id = t.id';
$criteria->condition = 't.type=:type AND (t.name LIKE :name OR addresses.address LIKE :name))';
$criteria->params = ['type'=>$type, 'name'=>'%'.$name.'%'];
$criteria->group = 't.id';
$models = Contractor::model()->findAll($criteria);
```